# ASP.Net MVC 3 Page Links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a web-site and having problem with links.

My Web-Site:
[My Web-Site](http://pixs.ru/showimage/Mywebsitep_4091622_9360855.png)
(I have second and third page, they are the same)

Web-Site from book:[Web-Site from book](http://pixs.ru/showimage/websitepng_7702104_9360824.png)

Problem: Do not put links that lead to other pages.

My code:

Controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public int PageSize = 4;

    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
    {
       ProductsListViewModel viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel{
           Products=repository.Products
            .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
            .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
            .Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItem = repository.Products.Count()
            }
    };
       return View(viewModel);
    }
```

HtmlHelper:

```
public static class PagingHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int,string> pageUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
            if (i == pagingInfo.CurentPage) 
            {
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
            }
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Models:

```
 public class PagingInfo
{
    public int TotalItem { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurentPage { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItem / ItemsPerPage); }
    }
}
```

And

```
public class ProductsListViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@foreach(var a in Model.Products)

{

  <div >
    <h4>@a.Name</h4>

    <h4>@a.Description</h4>

    <h4>@a.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
  </div>
}


<div class="pager">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo,x=>Url.Action("List", new {page=x}))
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please re-frame your question?

Comment: is there a reason you don't use @Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller")?

Comment: @HaBo I need links to each page, but it show only one link, like in the photo (My Web-Site)

Comment: @MattBodily: @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo,x=>Url.Action("List", new {page=x})) - this code must create me links to each page, even if I will add more products to DataBase, this code must automatically create new links to new pages

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UrlHelper.GenerateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.generateurl%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
The UrlHelper.GenerateUrl in ASP.NET MVC can be used to return a string which contains the URL.